# codeigniter 2.0 to 3.0 xml output broken

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

After migrating to CI 3.0 from 2.0 I'm having a problem with xml output. I do that through restserver with this code on the controller:

```
$xml = $this->_toRss($q);
$this->response->format = 'xml';
$this->response($xml, 200 );
```

$xml is an SimpleXMLElement which I create and assemble with code like this:

```
$xmlRoot = new SimpleXMLElement("<rss/>");
$xml = $xmlRoot;
$xml->addAttribute("version", "1.0");

$channel = $xml->addChild("channel");
$channel->addChild("title", "My Company");
$channel->addChild("link", xml_convert($curURL));
$channel->addChild("description", "RSS feed");
```

The code did not change on this migration.

Here is an example of the response working on 2.0:
http://pastebin.com/JfNNJeH7

And here is an example of the response on 3.0:
http://pastebin.com/ubDCNnhD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be registered as a bug on restserver but here is a workaround for whoever needs it:

```
$this->output->set_status_header(200);
$this->output->set_content_type('application/xml', strtolower($this->config->item('charset')));
$this->output->set_output($xml->asXML());
```